# What is the consequence for opening connection in psycopg2 without closing it?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have multiple worker processing job from a queue, and during the processing each worker opens a connection without closing it. Is there any consequence in doing so?

For example

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="my_db_name",
    user="my_user",
    password="my_password",
    host="my_host",
    port="5432")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
cur.fetchone()
conn.commit()
# What happen if I omit the line below for each job?
# cur.close()
# conn.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it required to close a Psycopg2 connection at the end of a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240830/is-it-required-to-close-a-psycopg2-connection-at-the-end-of-a-script), stressing the word "possible".

Comment: In short: when the `conn` object goes out of scope, and if no other references to it exist, [it will be closed](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.close). The exact timing depends on your Python implementation.

Comment: You may observe idle (or idle in transaction if you don't commit) connections.